# Routing error with registration controller using devise

Tags: routes, devise

I want to display email confirmation instructions to user after the sign up.

I overridden after_inactive_sign_up_path_for

def after_inactive_sign_up_path_for(resource)
   awaiting_confirmation (resource)
end

i added a an action in the registration controller awaiting_confirmation

def awaiting_confirmation(resource)
   render 'awaiting_confirmation'
 end

I added a view awaiting_confirmation.html.erb

After signup i manage to invoke the awaiting awaiting_confirmation action, but then i get the following an error message:

Render and/or redirect were called multiple times in this action. Please note that you may only call render OR redirect, and at most once per action. Also note that neither redirect nor render terminate execution of the action, so if you want to exit an action after redirecting, you need to do something like "redirect_to(...) and return".

Answer (score 0, accepted):

found the problem. it was a routing issue.
Aded this line:
devise_for :accounts do 
    match "awaiting_confirmation"    => "my_devise/registrations#awaiting_confirmation"
 end